# Desvio condicional não funcionando - Assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

Fui escrever um programinha em assembly com o compilador **NASM** no Xubuntu, tá aí o código:

```
    section .data        ;1
        msg db "Olá"     ;2
        n1 db 10         ;3
        n2 db 1          ;4
        len equ $-msg    ;5
                         ;6
    section .text        ;7
        global _start    ;8
        _start:          ;9
            mov rax, n1  ;10
            cmp rax, n2  ;11
            ja end       ;12
            mov rdx, len ;13
            mov rcx, msg ;14
            mov rbx, 1   ;15
            mov rax, 4   ;16
            int 80h      ;17
         end:            ;18
            mov rbx, 0   ;19
            mov rax, 1   ;20
            int 80h      ;21
```

Teoricamente, quando chegasse na linha 12 era pro programa pular pro label "end", já que está sendo feito um desvio mas por algum motivo o programa continua a execução normal.

Comment: Eu não entendo nada de Assembly, mas pelo que li o `ja` tem a condição de pular só se o valor do cmp mais recente for satisfeito, no caso tem que ser maior ou igual, se o objetivo é pular de qualquer forma, independente do cmp teria que usar `jmp` (não estou certo, não entendo bem, foi só o que li em uma documentação, posso ter compreendido errado). Agora se o objetivo é mesmo baseado na condição então o problema esta no "valor" do `cmp` mais recente. Desculpe se eu estiver equivocado em algo.

Comment: Tente colocar [] e testar novamente: `mov rax, [n1]` e `cmp rax,[n2]`. Você tem que ler valores a partir da memória, mas está lendo valores imediatos.

Answer (score 0):

A instrução `mov rax, n1` (linha 10) move para `rax` uma palavra de 64 *bits*, que corresponde ao endereço de memória representado pela *label* `n1`.
Na sintaxe Intel, um operando em memória representa-se encerrando o endereço entre parêntesis retos. Neste caso escrever-se-ia `mov rax, [n1]`.

Mesmo assim, não seria solução suficiente. A instrução `mov rax, [n1]` moveria para `rax` a palavra de 64 *bits* armazenada em memória no endereço `n1` e seguintes. `n1` é uma *label* para uma palavra de 8 *bits* (`db`) que corresponde a uma única posição de memória. Essa instrução iria descarregar em `al` o conteúdo de `n1`, em `ah` o conteúdo de `n2` e no resto de `rax`, o conteúdo das seis posições de memória seguintes.

A instrução `cmp rax, [n2]` também realizaria uma operação a 64 bits, sendo o segundo operando o conteúdo das oito posições de memória a partir de `n2`.

Não se conhecendo o conteúdo dessas posições de memória, não se  pode prever o comportamento da instrução `ja`.

Solução 1 - Definir n1 e n2 como variáveis a 64 *bits*

```
n1 dq 10
n2 dq 1

...
mov  rax, [n1]
cmp  rax, [n2]
...
```

Solução 2 - Realizar operações a 8 *bits*

```
mov  al, [n1]
cmp  al, [n2]
```